# Full command not visible using ps in solaris

Tags: unix, solaris, ps

the command that was run by cronjob

```
bin/bash /abc/bcd/def/ghi/connectivity/connectivity_script.sh start tof as abcde with abc/abc.prop
```

But while i try to see this process using

```
/usr/ucb/ps -auwwwxxxx | egrep "connectivity_script.sh"  | cat
```

i just see the below , but not the entire command.

```
bin/bash /abc/bcd/def/ghi/connectivity/connectivity_script.sh start tof as
```

How to fetch the entire command that was run using ps as i need to know which property file has been used?

> abc/abc.prop in this case

Comment: add `-o args`, the Solaris ps does not have the same parameters as the Linux one, read the man page.

Comment: Which version of Solaris?   There are significant changes in Solaris 11.3. See https://blogs.oracle.com/casper/solaris-113-sru-56:-updates-in-ps1-and-procltpidgtcmdline,environ,execname

Answer (score 4):

You may use in Solaris:

```
pargs -l PID
```

to get all arguments of process in one line if you know its PID. 
Also you may get the particular argument of process in such way:

```
pargs -a PID | grep 'argv\[8\]' | cut -d: -f 2
```

Or you may use ps with options if you know only one of process arguments:

```
/usr/bin/ps -A -o pid,args | grep connectivity_script.sh | grep -v grep
```

In older Solaris versions ouput of arguments in /usr/bin/ps is limited with 80 chars, so you need two-steps to do: 1) get PID from ps, 2) get full args from pargs.

```
PID=$(/usr/bin/ps -A -o pid,args | \
      grep connectivity_script.sh | \
      grep -v grep | \
      cut -d" " -f 1 )
pargs -l $PID
```

Comment: first command actually shows the entire command . but the third one did not work, and i do not have anyway to get the pid unless i grep it

Comment: or i ll have to save the pid of every command run in a new file and check it when needed

Comment: For older Solaris try this:
pargs -l $(/usr/bin/ps -A -o pid,args | grep connectivity_script.sh | grep -v grep | cut -d" " -f 1). This captures PID from 80-char args grep and then watches full info about this PID.

Comment: "
sasha  /usr/bin/ps  is never giving the full output.

Comment: Also i am getting output with /usr/ucb/ps -auwwwxxxx | egrep "connectivity.sh start fot as fot-"  but not with /usr/ucb/ps -aeuwwwxxxx | egrep "connectivity.sh start fot as fot-"  , -e is working if the string is long but it doesnt show anything if the string is short

Comment: @LearningCpp - /usr/bin/ps on Solaris is limited to 80 characters unless you upgrade to Solaris 11.3.5 or later which added the kernel interface necessary for it to show more.

Answer (score 2):

As Sasha says, `pargs` is the best (and only, on older versions of Solaris) way to look at a process's entire argument vector, but `pgrep` is the best way to find the process in the first place.  Because the thing you're searching for is not the name of the executable, you'll need the `-f` argument.  Thus:

```
pgrep -f connectivity_script.sh
```

Combining with `pargs`:

```
pargs $(pgrep -f connectivity_script.sh)
```

Note that unless you own the process or have elevated privilege, you won't be able to see the entire argument vector of a process, and so the pgrep invocation may fail to find what you're looking for, and pargs definitely won't show it.  That limitation is present even in the newer versions of Solaris Andrew mentioned.